# How to make IE 8 not to show anything to an iFrame before onload element is finished?

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8, coding-style, onload

I want to hide elements of an website loaded in an iFrame. The script and the site can take a while so it is requested that the iFrame content is only shown after it has been modified.

I use an onload event to execute the script which hides the elements. I have access to the iFrame content (it's on the same domain, but not the same server / network).

```
function frameLoaded() {
sleep(3000); //simulating the time the script needs
var leftDiv = window.frames.testFrame.document.getElementById("leftcol");
leftDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

The simple sleep function:

```
function sleep(milliSeconds){
var startTime = new Date().getTime(); // get the current time
while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds); // hog cpu
}
```

When the Website with the iFrame is loaded for the first time a scroll-bar and some styled elements are shown, but no content text:

http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/5082/beforeu.png

When the script is done the page is displayed as it should be (the azure colored div becomes hidden):

http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/6806/afterq.png

While the script is working there shouldn't be displayed anything. Either an empty iframe or the whole website waiting till the onload is finished would be sufficient.

Comment: Are you loading in one of your own sites?  Or is it a third party site?  I only ask because if you can add some javascript to the site being loaded in the IFrame, you could put in the following line document.body.onload = function() {parent.frameLoaded();} and get rid of all those sleep function calls.

Comment: It is third party. The sleep is just there to simulate a "long" script execution time. Apparently it is really possible that the script will take some time. It will be rather complex and also is accessed by smartphones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the `<iframe id="iframe" style="display: none">` hidden on your parent page load and on the `onload` event of the iframe set this one to visible:

```
function frameLoaded() {
  sleep(3000); //simulating the time the script needs
  var leftDiv = window.frames.testFrame.document.getElementById("leftcol");
  leftDiv.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("iframe").style.display = 'block';
}
```

BTW: This sleep function should be thrown away.

Comment: Thanks, could have thought about that myself >.<
PS: The sleep is just there to simulate a "long" script execution time.